# How does this inequality imply this one?

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I am having a little trouble understanding this part of a proof.

There is an integral $\text{J}_{n} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^2\cos^{2n}x dx$

Now, $\text{J}_0 = \frac{\pi ^3}{24} $

The part of the proof I am unable to understand says that 
$x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}\sin x $ for every $0 \lt x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

They are saying that thus inequality implies that 
$$\text{J}_n \lt \frac{\pi^2}{4} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2x \cos^{2n} x dx $$

I am unable to supply the intermediate steps. Please help.

Comment: That seems a typo. The correct inequality you would like to apply is $x < \frac{\pi}{2}\sin x$ when $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee you are right. It was a typo. I corrected it but I still don't know how to fill in the steps.

Comment: Did you get the part where this inequality implies your last inequality involving $\mathrm{J}_n$? It is straightforward, so I assume you did and you are asking about the inequality $x < \frac{\pi}{2}\sin x$. This follows from the strict convexity of the sine function on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Actually I am asking about how it implies the final inequality. I must be missing something.. I'm not finding it straightforward.

Comment: If I am not misunderstood, you can just bound your integrand using $$ x^2 \cos^{2n} x < (\tfrac{\pi}{2}\sin x)^2 \cos^{2n}x, \quad 0< x < \tfrac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Wow! That is a brilliant insight! Thanks. I struggled with this for nearly an hour.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have a question and it may sound silly. If $A\lt B$, does it imply $\int A \lt \int B$ within the same limits of integration.

Comment: Sure. If in addition they are non-negative functions, you may as well recognize it as an inequality between areas under the graph of $A$ and $B$. That is, it is simply read as 'larger shape has bigger area'.

Comment: Only one observation to your last comment: $A<B$ doesn't implie $\int A<\int B$. The correct statement is $A<B$ implies $\int A\le\int B$ (equality can be satisfied)

Comment: @sinbadh When can equality hold?